# An item with the same key has already been added. error due to multiple time call to embedded DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, modbus-tcp

I have add one dll as embedded resource in my windows forms application. I got code how to use embedded dll in my windows forms application.

This code used:

```
   public PanContext() : base("ConnectionString")
        {               
            string modbus = "PLCBots.Services.NModbus4.dll";
            EmbeddedAssembly.Load(modbus, "NModbus4.dll");    
        }
```

now got a problem that my embeddded reourcs is load multiple time and i got error 
**An item with the same key has already been added.**

Is any thing in windows forms application like DependencyRegister.cs file we have in ASP.NET MVC ?

Please guide me so my above written code will not call again & again.

Comment: You can use the static constructor to avoid loading the same assembly multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender,
   ResolveEventArgs args)
           {
               return EmbeddedAssembly.Get(args.Name);
           }

User this in you main startup point of application